# Generalized Gell-Mann Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematical-physics

The [Generalized Hermitian Gell-Mann Matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices#Generalized_Gell-Mann_matrices_.28Hermitian.29) (in dimension $d$ ) consist of the $h_k^d$, where $1\leq k \leq d$, and the $f_{k,j}^d$, where $1\leq k, j\leq d$.

There should be $2^d -1$ matrices in dimension $d$.  But here there is only $d-1$ from the $h$ type and maybe $d^2 -d$ of the $f$ type?

Comment: Aren't the generalized Pauli/Gell-Mann matrices just bases for the Lie algebra su(N) as a real vector space? So your intuition of $2^N-1$ matrices is correct.

Comment: Okay, yes, I think that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's $d^2 - 1$ matrices in dimension $d$, not $2^d-1$. [Here is a prescription for generating the matrices](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedGell-MannMatrix.html).

The $d^2-1$ matrices can be categorized as follows:

- $d-1$ diagonal matrices,
- ${d}\choose{2}$ "symmetric" matrices
- ${d}\choose{2}$ "anti-symmetric" matrices

In total this becomes:

$$\tag{1}
\frac{d(d-1)}{2} + \frac{d(d-1)}{2} + (d-1) = d^2-1.
$$

This decomposition is also given explicitly in Eqs. 3-5 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.1174).

In the Wikipedia article that you referenced, the identity matrix is included, so there would be $d^2$ matrices, not just $d^2 - 1$.